# The best way to achieve scala runtime compilation module

Tags: scala

I'm writing a run-time compilation module. Code is as follows:

```
    val settings = new Settings
    settings.usejavacp.value = true
    val interpreter = new IMain(settings)
    interpreter.interpret(""" val result = the scala code here """)    
    interpreter.valueOfTerm("result")//return the result var
```

But I have some problem.

1. How to let multiple threads call IMain return different results?  Is assigned  a IMain instance to a thread? This will be a waste of computer resources (non-stop compilation)
2. how to redefine has been compiled class?
3. interpreter generated variables (such as the "result") will always be preserved? How to remove the temporary variable? Is there a better api can be called directly, or how to improve my code?